# Start the Nodejs and Docker then pass parameter to index.js in single statement

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, containers

I have written a program using the Node.js it uses the MySQL from the docker. Also, my node.js has the Index.js file which requires the input from the user based on which it will continue with different types of operation. In order to execute this, I need to run the following commands.

`1. docker-compose up --build -d`  which will start the various containers.

`2. docker-compose exec web sh -c "npm start"` which will start the Node.js application.

`3. one` parameter provided by the user which will be taken by index.js and based on the parameter different database operation can be performed.

Now I wanted to remove these 3 different steps and merge them to make one so that users can provide just a single line query and it can be read and execution be started. Is there a way to merge these things and execute them all together.

My `index.js` file looks something like this:

```
const   express     =   require('express');
const   http        =   require("http");
const   bodyParser  =   require('body-parser');
const   app         =   express();
const   basePath    =   __dirname;
const   path        =   require('path');
const   reqPath     =   path.join(__dirname, './');
const   fs          =   require('fs');
const   port        =   process.env.PORT || 9000;
app.use(bodyParser.json()); 
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

//Make NodeJS to Listen to a particular Port in Localhost
app.listen(port, function(){
getInput(function(data){
if(data.trim() === "Player")
{
 console.log("ONE");
}
});
    });

//function to take the input from the user and return it to calling function
function getInput(callback)
{
    var standard_input = process.stdin;
    standard_input.setEncoding('utf-8');
    standard_input.on('data', function (data) {
        callback(data);
    });
}
```

Here is my `docker-compose.yaml` file with all the services:

```
version: '3'

services:
  db:
    container_name: db
    image: mysql:5.7
    volumes:
      - "./data/mysql:/var/lib/mysql:rw"
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: database
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
      MYSQL_USER: rootuser
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: password
      DATABASE_HOST: 127.0.01
    restart: always

  web:
    container_name: web
    image: node:8
    volumes:
      - ./web:/usr/src/app
    working_dir: /usr/src/app
    depends_on:
      - db
    restart: on-failure
    command: "tail -f /dev/null"
    environment:
      project: ${project}
      type: ${type}
```

Answer (score 1):

To avoid having to type the `docker-compose exec` command, you can look into defining a `command` or an `entrypoint` for that container (`web`) in your `docker-compose.yaml` file. See [the Compose file documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#entrypoint). This will tell your container which command to run on start-up.

Then you could for instance make your `index.js` accept parameters from somewhere else than user input. I would make it read environment variables instead, and bind it via `docker-compose.yaml`. So, Node-side, instead of `getInput()`, you'd use `process.env.MY_INPUT_VARIABLE`. And Compose-side, you could add an environment variable to your `web` service by using the `environment:` key, looking like:

```
services:
  web:
    environment:
      MY_INPUT_VARIABLE: ${MY_INPUT_VARIABLE_HOST}
```

Then run docker-compose up in a small bash script that uses its first argument (`"$1"`) to define and to export an environment variable "MY_INPUT_VARIABLE_HOST", then runs your `docker-compose up` command. When `docker-compose` runs, it will read `${MY_INPUT_VARIABLE_HOST}` and replace it with the value of the variable. It will assign it to `MY_INPUT_VARIABLE` inside the container, and Node will be able to read it in its `process.env`.

Assuming you call the bash script something like `run-containers`, the single command `./run-containers Player` will do the same as running your `docker-compose up` command, followed by your `docker-compose exec` command, followed by entering `Player` when prompted by Node.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I am able to accept the variables from the Environment now but I did not understand the entry point. I have posted my docker-compose.yaml file above can you please let me know more on that.

Comment: @BATMAN_2008 Right now, your `web` service has a `command` set to `tail -f /dev/null`, meaning it will do nothing particularly useful on startup. If you replace it with a different command, like `npm start`, this command will be the one that is run when the container starts. `tail -f /dev/null` is a neat trick to run a container that will never crash, but it isn't very useful because the container starts doing nothing. Now, entrypoints are a different way to specify what to run at container startup, but you can probably ignore that for now, it won't matter in your scenario.

Comment: Thanks for the response. So is it possible for me to remove the command `tail -f /dev/null` and replace it with the `entrypoint` so that my docker will start and it will automatically listen to ´web´? or can you please suggest me any other alternative method?